# VB.Net Textbox Autocomplete Selected Item

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

I have a vb.net form with a textbox on it set to autocomplete custom collection from a database. Is there an event that fires when a user finds the value they want from the autocomplete list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The KeyDown event fires with e.KeyCode = 13 when the user presses Enter or Double Clicks on an item in the list.

Comment: Simple solution, Thanks!

Comment: Awesome share - would never have got that!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Aucomplete for Textbox in** **vb.net**

```
Private Sub txtFilterBy_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilterBy.TextChanged
  txtSearch("Select Name From items", txtFilterBy)
End Sub

Public Sub txtSearch(ByVal strsql As String, ByVal textboxName As TextBox)
  con.ConnectionString = constr
  Excercise_Add.con.Open()
  Dim namesCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
  cmd = New MySqlCommand(strsql,con)
  da.SelectCommand = cmd
  read = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  While (read.Read)
    namesCollection.Add(read(0).ToString())
  End While
  textboxName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
  textboxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection
  textboxName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
  con.Close()
End Sub
```